# samsung xcover 3 TYPE_GYROSCOPE dont work

Tags: java, android

When i look on specifications in xcover 3 they write this model have Gyroscope.

I tried write code(i use android studio) to see how its work but it didnt show me this sensor on this model or android virtual device.

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{




boolean running = false;
SensorManager sensorManager; 
ToggleButton btn; 
TextView textView;
TextView x1;
TextView y1;
TextView z1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    btn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

  btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          if(isChecked){

              running = true;

          }


            else{

           running = false;


      }}
  });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Sensor countsensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    if(countsensor != null){
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,countsensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
   }
    else{

       Toast.makeText(this, "Brak sensora",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(running){


        x1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewX1);
        y1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewY1);
        z1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewZ1);

        x1.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        y1.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
        z1.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));



    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}}
```

in this part countsensor return null.

```
     @Override
        protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Sensor countsensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        if(countsensor != null){ 
 sensorManager.registerListener(this,countsensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASEST);
       }
        else{

           Toast.makeText(this, "Brak sensora",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

When i change Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE to Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER all work fine. 
I'm so confused why its not working.

Answer (score 1):

According to this website this device does not have a gyroscope:

https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_xcover_3-6990.php

You can simply check if the gyroscope is present in your device with this few lines of code:

```
boolean gyro;

gyro = sensorMgr.registerListener(this,sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

if(gyro) 
{
//code to execute if gyro is present
}
```